# Redis sentinel failover, choose specific master

Tags: redis, high-availability, redis-sentinel

I have 3 replicated Redis instances running on 3 different machines: A, B and C.
I initially choose A as my master.
I also have 3 sentinels (1 on each machine) monitoring A.

In case A goes down, I want sentinels to choose a specific master to failover to (say B).
Is there a way to choose a specific master instead of leaving it to the election mechanism of the sentinels?

Since I couldn't find this question anywhere, I reckon it's not standard procedure so I'll explain the reason behind it:
My application is running on A, B and C behind a load balancer.
The master uses its **local** Redis db which is replicated to the other two slaves.

When A fails, the load balancer could choose B as master while Redis sentinels could elect C as Redis master.
As I just said, I need the instance to be local, so that's why I need to specify B as the Redis master.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a Redis configuration setting called 'slave-priority' that may help you out.

Reference: 
http://download.redis.io/redis-stable/redis.conf